# Replicated sketched lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art

How do I replicate these analogues created circular lines? they have a randomly variying strengths and gaps within. I am not talking about in between two circles but the line of any given circle

[image: -i]

Comment: You should use brushes

Answer (score 2):

Create the circles, then apply various brushes to the paths.....

[image]